# Value of BlipExtension Schema URI: "28A0092B-C50C-407e-A947-70E740481C1C"

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, drawing, openxml

**Question**

The class `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlipExtension` has a property called `Uri`.  In numerous examples I've seen the value `28A0092B-C50C-407e-A947-70E740481C1C` used; but never found what this value is / whether it's important, or if it's arbitrary and only prevalent because of people copy-pasting from existing sample code.

Does anyone know what the relevance of this GUID value is?

**Background**

I've been fixing a bug in a legacy application, and have been refactoring at the same time to remove some of the code's spaghettification.

Whilst doing this I spotted a few hardcoded values;
any image inserted into the document is given the name `Koala.jpg`.  The system has nothing to do with Koalas; implying that the person had simply copy-pasted some code and not thought about the context / meaning of these values.
Another hardcoded value is the Uri for a BlipExtension: `28A0092B-C50C-407e-A947-70E740481C1C`.
I wanted to determine whether this GUID has any particular meaning, or if it's just a unique value.  Googling shows this value used in lots of sample code, but so far I've found no explanation of what it is.  Example results below.

- https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-PL/library/bb497430(v=office.14).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb (with Koala.jpg)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430.aspx
- [Insert an image into word document using open xml and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155987/insert-an-image-into-word-document-using-open-xml-and-c-sharp)

Looking at the BlipExtension documentation doesn't give much info on how I could find out what this GUID is / what schema this refers to.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.drawing.blipextension.uri(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: 1. MSDN appears to be down so I couldn't read up on the BlipExtension class. I can, however, tell you what Koala.jpg is: it's the file name of one of the Sample pictures provided with Windows. So it makes sense that you'd see this in a sample document.

Comment: 2. For more information about BlipExtension I recommend the ECMA documentation for the Office Open XML spec. That goes into great detail. It can be downloaded for free from the ECMA site. For more clarification you can try asking in the MSDN forum for Open specifications (includes binary and other file formats). The Microsoft engineers (and not "contingent staff") monitor that forum. Unfortunately I'm travelling currently so can't give you a link...

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister.  Looking through the documentation now... http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

Comment: Sadly no luck checking the spec (searching for the GUID).  I've now asked here also: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/056472c8-31cd-42e1-b527-5921aef16a24/value-of-blipextension-schema-uri-28a0092bc50c407ea94770e740481c1c?forum=os_binaryfile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like it's a specific value for the `useLocalDpi` extension.

The [[MS-ODRAWXML]: Office Drawing Extensions to Office Open XML Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd905216%28v=office.12%29.aspx) document lists many extensions to the DrawingML spec, each with their own unique Guid Uri attribute.

[Section 2.3.1.13](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd909841%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is the section that mentions `28A0092B-C50C-407e-A947-70E740481C1C` as the *Extension list URI attribute* for the `useLocalDpi` extension. It looks like this setting was introduced in Word 2010 so an extension was added to support it.

As @Cindy Meister pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521914/value-of-blipextension-schema-uri-28a0092b-c50c-407e-a947-70e740481c1c#comment54826186_33521914) the Koala.jpg file is a sample picture that is provided with (many versions of) Windows.